# How to remove the boundaries

Tags: perl

ALL,

I have a text file which contains following lines:

```
123
abc
def
ghi
456
```

I am trying to process this file with Perl and I need to get the lines that start with letters, i.e.

```
abc
def
ghi
```

There is a `...` operator which gives lines in the files but including boundaries, so it will include boundaries.

Is there an easy way to get the lines without boundaries?

Thank you.

Comment: `perl -ne 'print if /^\pL/' file` perhaps? Or just use `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
perl -lne '/^\D+$/ and print' file.txt
```

`\D` is a short-hand to *what's not a number*